# How to split a timestamped log file in multiple files, by day, using awk

Tags: bash, awk, split, timestamp

I have a large log file, going back a few years, which looks like this:

```
[2017-02-16T15:59+02:00] some log data
[2017-02-17T16:03+02:00] some other log data
[2017-02-17T16:05+02:00] yet another log data
```

I want to split it in separate files. Each file should include all the messages in a single day. The filenames should be something like `log-2017-02-16.txt`.

I did some research and found some similar questions, but I have no experience with awk to be able to translate the answers to what I need.

Comment: something like this `awk -F'[]T[]' '{print > "log-"$2".txt"}' input_file`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this awk command for that:

```
awk -F '[\\[T]' '{print > "log-" $2 ".txt"}' file
```

- `-F '[\\[T]'` sets input field separator as `[` or `T`
- `"log-" $2 ".txt"` will format required file name
  0 `print > ..` will redirect each record into a file

Comment: Got the basic idea from this and combined seprator for nginx format from the another. Thx :)